# DRF IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: user_id

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-database

I can't figure out how to pass user object to the following serializer:

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('pk', 'title', 'user', 'movie', 'timestamp', 'review_text',)
```

I have this viewset:

```
class ReviewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Review.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
```

and this model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    review_text = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{movie} review by {user}'.format(user=self.user, movie=self.movie)
```

My javascript request looks like this:

```
return axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/reviews/',
  data: { // Using data from Vue
    title: this.review_title,
    movie: this.id,
    review_text: this.review_text,
    user: JSON.stringify(this.user)
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `JWT ${token}`
  }
})
```

It gives me [this traceback](http://dpaste.com/144C4KH).

How should I pass the user object to the request?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove **`read_only=True`** from serializer

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('pk', 'title', 'user', 'movie', 'timestamp', 'review_text',)
```

If you set **`read_only=True`**, the DRF ***will not takes the value from input source*** even if it's there

[From the doc,](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only)

> Read-only fields are included in the API output, but should not be
>   included in the input during create or update operations. Any
>   'read_only' fields that are incorrectly included in the serializer
>   input will be ignored.
>
> Set this to **`True`** to ensure that the field is used when serializing a
>   representation, but is not used when creating or updating an instance
>   during deserialization.
>
> Defaults to **`False`**

**UPDATE**
You should override the **`create()`** method of **`ReviewSerializer`** as

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_dict = validated_data.pop('user')
        user_obj, created = User.objects.get_or_create(**user_dict)
        return Review.objects.create(user=user_obj, **validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('pk', 'title', 'user', 'movie', 'timestamp', 'review_text',)
```

**for debug purpose only**

```
class ReviewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Review.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)  # print here <<<<
        return super(ReviewsViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yes, but If I take out `read_only=True` it gives me: `"A user with that username already exists."`. So, I don't want to post a new user, just to take the user data needed to create that particular review.

Comment: Can you add the value of `user` that you're passing from front-end?

Comment: @yierstem Anyway I've updated the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: I pass the whole user object that I stored in Vuex so I can display user details and stuff. So it looks like this `"{"pk":1,"username":"test","first_name":"test","last_name":"test","email":"test@gmail.com"}"`. I sent a request with all of the fields required, especially user field, and returns another error: `"user": [ "This field is required." ]`.

Comment: Yes, I edited the serializer according to your answer.

Comment: The error says that the `user` data not reaching to DRF view

Comment: @yierstem print the data in DRF view and add it here, (check the updated answe)

Comment: It does not reach create() method. I tried your updated answer, it displays nothing, only `Bad request` and the status code. Note: I tried to display some random string, to see if it displays anything at all.

Comment: create method of view or serializer?

Comment: Oh, sorry, It was for the viewset, since it has request, my bad. Here: `<QueryDict: {'review_text': ['something'], 'title': ['Something'], 'user': ['{"pk":1,"username":"test","first_name":"test","last_name":"test","email":"test@gmail.com"}'], 'movie': ['8']}>`

Comment: Can you add the result of `print(type(request.data['user']))` in `create()` method of **view** ?

Comment: `<class 'str'>` is the output

Comment: Then, Change `user: JSON.stringify(this.user)` to `user: this.user` in your JS code

Comment: Oh, ok, now it's working. Thank you for detalied answer, I learned a bit how to debug DRF now.

Answer (score 0):

just add this

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    # new line
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = (
            'pk', 'title', 'user', 'movie', 'timestamp', 'review_text',
            'user_id', # new field
        )
```

> **[read_only](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only)**
>
> Read-only fields are included in the API output, but should not be included in the input during create or update operations. Any 'read_only' fields that are incorrectly included in the serializer input will be ignored.
>
> Set this to True to ensure that the field is used when serializing a representation, but is not used when creating or updating an instance during deserialization.
>
> Defaults to False

> **[write_only](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#write_only)**
>
> Set this to True to ensure that the field may be used when updating or creating an instance, but is not included when serializing the representation.
>
> Defaults to False